# Bootstrap - Modal togging works, but doesn't close the first modal

Tags: html, css

Section 1

```
<div
  class="modal fade show"
  id="ft"
  data-bs-backdrop="static"
  data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
  style="display: block; padding-right: 17px"
  aria-modal="true"
  role="dialog"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="ftt">How to use Flash after 2021</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <i>
          To close this page, click the X button, or the "Close" button to
          close. Clicking off the pop-up will not work.
        </i>
        <h2>Example Heading</h2>
        <p>
          Example Sentence. Find a browser that allows Flash plug-ins, you can
          visit
          <a href="#" data-bs-target="#br" data-bs-toggle="modal">this page</a>
          to find some.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Section 2

```
<div
  class="modal fade show"
  id="br"
  data-bs-backdrop="static"
  data-bs-keyboard="false"
  tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
  style="display: block; padding-right: 17px"
  aria-modal="true"
  role="dialog"
>
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="brt">How to use Flash after 2021</h5>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn-close"
          data-bs-dismiss="modal"
          aria-label="Close"
        ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <i>
          To close this page, click the X button, or the "Close" button to
          close. Clicking off the pop-up will not work.
        </i>
        <h2>Example Heading</h2>
        <p>Example Sentence. to find some.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hello, the community of StackOverflow. This contains examples of two modals. In section 1, the tag works, by going to the other modal, section 2, togging the two. But, the two models are still open, while section 1 is supposed to be closed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried adding `data-bs-dismiss="modal"` to the anchor?

Comment: Yes, it just closes the modal.

Comment: Nevermind, @ArleighHix, I put it alongside data-bs-toggle, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

could add managger of modals

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
    var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
    $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
        $(".modal.fade.multi-modal").css("overflow-y", "auto");
    }, 0);
});
```

if you are use jquery could open the modal with

```
  $('#ft').modal({ 'backdrop': 'static', 'keyboard': false });
  $('#ft').modal('show');
```

and for close

```
  $('#WGTSCPDetallesModificacion').modal('hide');
```

I hope I could have helped you :)

Comment: Tried all of the code here. Added the script tag to the end of the body tag. Didn't work at all.

Comment: try with  jquery-1.12.4.min